# ListBox.SelectedIndex in ContextMenu event handler

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, contextmenu

I have a listbox with context menu. How can I get value of SelectedIndex (SelectedItem) property in ContextMenuItem click event handler? Currently in events Edit_Click and Delete_CLick a value of CarsList.SelectedIndex always is -1.

Here my ListBox in XAML:

> ```
>            <ListBox Name="CarsList" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}" Margin="26,0,26,0" Height="380" >
>                 <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
>                     <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="ContextMenu" >
>                         <toolkit:MenuItem Name="Edit" Header="Edit" Click="Edit_Click"/>
>                         <toolkit:MenuItem Name="Delete"  Header="Delete" Click="Delete_Click"/>
>                     </toolkit:ContextMenu>
>                 </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
>                 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
>                     <DataTemplate>
>                         <StackPanel>
>                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding CarName}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Foreground="Black" FontSize="24" Width="428"/>
>                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding VIN}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="20" Width="428"/>
>                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="20" Width="428"/>
>                         </StackPanel>
>                     </DataTemplate>
>                 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
>             </ListBox>
> ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all you have assigned `Context Menu` to `ListBox` control, not an each item. So, move `<toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>` block to `StackPanel` instead.

There are several ways to get element, on which context menu click was performed:

In `Click` handler you have `sender` object (it is `MenuItem`, I guess)

Cast it to `MenuItem` and look to `DataContext` of it. It will be item of collection you binded to a list. So, you can find index by:

```
int selectedIndex = YourListBoxItemCollection.IndexOf((sender as MenuItem).DataContext)
```

, where `YourListBoxItemCollection` is what you assign to `CarsList.ItemsSource`

Comment: I moved ContextMenu block to StackPanel and assigned to ListBox.ItemsSource value "Cars" for example. But I have an error in code 
>int selectedIndex = Cars.IndexOf((sender as UIElement).DataContext); //can't find definition of DataContext for System.Windows.UIElement

What's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, `DataContext` is in `FrameworkElement`. Try it or `MenuItem` instead of `UIElement`. It should work

Comment: ListBoxItem contextMenuListItem = CarsList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem((sender as ContextMenu).DataContext) as ListBoxItem; //found this code but it throws an exception NullReferenceException. And I don't understand how can I read values of my textboxes in ItemTemplate?

Comment: Please, debug code step-by-step. `var Menu = sender as ContextMenu;` `Car car = Menu.DataContext as Car;` `int index = Cars.IndexOf(Car);` Where you have an exception?

Comment: Thanks for help and tips :) It's working now (solution is below, under the second answer).

Comment: Your answers are useful, but I can't raise your reputation yet :( Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use ListPicker (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888) with SelectedItems.
OR
Add some flag of element selection...

Comment: Solved. Used this FAQ: http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-contextmenu-answers-to-popular-questions

Comment: For future questions: >ListBoxItem selectedListBoxItem = CarsList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem((sender as MenuItem).DataContext) as ListBoxItem;
            int SelectedIndex = CarsList.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(selectedListBoxItem);

Comment: It's work but it's interesting is there any optimization for this code or more flexible solution? Thanks to all for answers.