# Windows Phone app - get index of item that called context menu

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, contextmenu

I have a ListBox with a context menu in it

```
<ListBox>

<toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>

<toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="True"x:Name="ContextMenu" >

<toolkit:MenuItem x:Name=”Open" Header=”Open Trailer" Click="nOpe_Click"/>



</toolkit:ContextMenu>

</toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>


</ListBox>
```

How do i get the Index of the ListBox Item that called the Open_Click event.

Answer (score 1):

Your Open_Click event should have an `Object sender` in its signature. This is what you have to work with.

Take the `sender` and cast it to the `MenuItem`. This `MenuItem` will have a `DataContext`

The `DataContext` of this `MenuItem` should be an item in your `ListBox`.

If you have a reference to that `ListBox`, then you can go

`var contextMenuOpenedIndex = ListBoxName.IndexOf((sender as MenuItem).DataContext)`

Here's the same question (and a reference):
[ListBox.SelectedIndex in ContextMenu event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259116/listbox-selectedindex-in-contextmenu-event-handler)

A sample ItemTemplate:

```
<ListBox x:Name="SampleListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                ... ContextMenu ... 
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>    
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I keep getting a -1 as the index. Here is my code:    http://pastebin.com/YGRjhJRd

Comment: Your code shows that you're putting the ContextMenu on the actual ListBox, not the individual item. You will want to put the ContextMenu inside the ItemTemplate of the ListBox, so each item in the ListBox will have its own ContextMenu.

Comment: , but i add the items using a for loop in code behind. I don't use an ItemTemplate for adding the items.

Comment: An ItemTemplate simply defines how you display the items, not how the ListBox is populated.

Comment: I define how the items are displaced by my loop (I create my items ) and then i add it to my ListBox.  What should i do? I dont use the template i do it myself.

Comment: it is a stackpanel that has and image control and a textblock control in it. I make 3 of these items, using a for loop. After the loop makes one, it adds it to the Listbox items, and then it makes the next one and adds it. etc..